# How to add class to HTML element depending on page-template?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to add a specific class `layout-red` to my div element if the page is using `section-about.php` or `section-contact.php` page-template files. If not, add class `layout-default`.

I've tried using the `is_template();` tag, but then tried `get_page_template_slug(get_the_ID()`

```
<?php 
    echo (get_page_template_slug);
    if ( get_page_template_slug(get_the_ID()) === 'section-about.php' ) {
        echo '<div id="wrapper" class="layout-red">';
    } else {
        echo '<div id="wrapper" class="layout-default">';
    }
?>
```

I expected there to be a `<div class="layout-red">`, but constantly end up with a `<div class="layout-default">`
If I insert a `var_dump(get_page_template_slug(get_the_ID()));` before the enitre cl, it returns string(32) "template-parts/section-about.php"

Comment: Before doing if, you can try to var_dump(get_page_template_slug(get_the_ID())) to see what actually is returned.

Comment: Could you provide us with further information about the returns of get_page_template_slug() and so on?

Comment: It returns `string(32) "template-parts/section-about.php"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use code below to resolve.

```
if ( basename(get_page_template_slug(get_the_ID()) === 'section-about.php' ) {
    echo '<div id="wrapper" class="layout-red">';
} else {
   echo '<div id="wrapper" class="layout-default">';
}
```

it is return the value of layout-red

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
global $template; echo basename($template); //return string of current page template
if ( basename($template) === 'section-about.php' ) {...}
```